# Using variables in PDO update statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Thanks to all of you who provided input. And yes i am very new to pdo and php programing so some basic errors that you guys might spot easily in my code aren't that apparent to me yet.

I think my explanation wasn't that clear so I'm gonna try again.

$newCoins is not a field in my table its just a temporary variable that stores some number i need to add to gold field. I Don't think i need to bind it.

$coinType is not a field but a variable that holds the name of a field. it can be anything silver,bronze etc. but in our example lets assume its gold.

gold is a field in my table.
there are 6 fields in my table. Another script does some calculations to determine what field to choose. in this case lets assume gold is chosen then assigned to $coinType
i use $coinType in a select statement to get the value in the gold field.

Problem is, after i get the value stored in the gold field and use it in a mathematical calculation I'm not sure how to return the new value back in the gold field. 
example $coinType is assigned the string "gold" which is used to reference the gold field.

$newCoins has a value and i want add it to the gold field but when i assign $newCoin to $coinType the string "gold" gets over written meaning reference to the gold field is lost.

Here is my syntax. I hope I'm a bit clear now. 
  I'm trying to assign the value from $newCoins  to the field " gold". gold is a string representing the name of a field. Gold is a string stored in $coinType.

$usr_check = $connDB->prepare("UPDATE coins SET `$coinType`='$newCoins' 
 WHERE '$coinType' = '$coinType");
$usr_check->bindParam(':coinType', $coinType, PDO::PARAM_INT);

Thanks in advance for looking.

```
<?php

$owner_id        = "Robert"; // the user id
$coinType        = "gold"; //this is the field that was randomly selected for update
$additionalCoins = 289; //add this number to whatever value already stored in gold field.

$usr_check = $connDB->prepare("SELECT 1 FROM coins WHERE owner_id = :owner_id");
$usr_check->bindParam(':owner_id', $owner_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$usr_check->execute();

if ($usr_check->rowCount() > 0) {

    $usr_check = $connDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM coins WHERE '$coinType' = '$coinType'");
    $usr_check->bindParam(':coinType', $coinType, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $usr_check->execute();
    # setting the fetch mode
    $usr_check->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $row          = $usr_check->fetch();
    $discounted_p = $row["$coinType"];
    $newCoins     = $discounted_p + $additionalCoins;

    $usr_check = $connDB->prepare("UPDATE coins SET '$coinType'='$newCoins' WHERE owner_id = :owner_id");
    $usr_check->bindParam(':$coinType', $coinType, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $usr_check->bindParam(':owner_id', $owner_id, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $usr_check->execute();
}
```

Comment: Sidenote: Remove the quotes from `WHERE '$coinType'` and `SET '$coinType'` --- those are columns. Use backticks

Comment: Replace $coinType with :coinType in the prepare and bind statements. That could be your problem.

Comment: Why do you have `:$coinType`?

Comment: What i forgot to mention is that $coinType is a variable that stores the string "gold". gold is the name of a field. Anyway, i updated my question to make things a bit more clear.

Answer (score -1):

One thing you are doing wrong is that you bind the $coinType, which is the column name. Youn need to bind the $newCoins.

Try this syntax:

```
$usr_check = $connDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM coins WHERE `$coinType` = :coinType");
    $usr_check->bindParam(':coinType', $coinType, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

and

```
$usr_check = $connDB->prepare("UPDATE coins SET `$coinType`=:newCoins 
 WHERE owner_id = :owner_id");
$usr_check->bindParam(':coinType', $coinType, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

Comment: Why two answers? Remove one, they're both the same.

Comment: no idea how this happened. I thought it was not even allowed!

Comment: I guess strange things happen sometimes. Btw, I did not downvote this, just so you know. I never downvote answers, *it's not my style*. ;-)

Comment: thanks Fred, no worries.I just hope the downvote was not for the 2 answers.

Comment: @Aris I originally mentioned in my first comment (edited out, sorry) that you made one of the same mistakes as the OP did, where OP is using variables for column names, which they should have been wrapped in backticks.

Comment: Guys i update my answer to also include the first wrong query and remove the quotes. I thought that the column name might be interpreted  anyways.

Comment: Please read my question again because I added more information to be more clear.

Comment: @Lightness you are plainly wrong. It might be bad practice to use a variable as column name, but it is what the goal is here, to actually update different fields...

Answer (score -1):

```
$owner_id        = "Robert";
$coinType        = "gold";
$additionalCoins = 289;

$allowed = ['gold','silver'];
if (in_array($coinType, $allowed))
{
    $sql = "UPDATE coins SET `$coinType` = `$coinType` + ? WHERE owner_id = ?";
    $stmt = $connDB->prepare($sql);
    $usr_check->execute([$additionalCoins, $owner_id]);
}
```

error-, injection- and repetipeptipetipetitions proof

Answer (score -1):

I think you are misunderstanding the PDO variable names (placeholders). You prepare a statement with the variable name preceded by a colon as follows:

```
$connDB->prepare("SELECT * FROM coins WHERE type = :coinType")
```

Passing parameters with `bindParam` uses this variable and assigns the value from you php variable to it.

```
$usr_check->bindParam(':coinType', $coinType);
```

This makes it unncessary to pass in the potentially insecure php variables directly into the sql statement.

See [PDOStatement::bindParam](http://php.net/manual/de/pdostatement.bindparam.php)

Comment: There is potentially insecure type, if you didn't notice

Comment: What would be the insecure type, did not use my common sense to notice ;).

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier thanks for that, correcting accordingly to take the default value.